# Chrome element inspection continuously jumping to Nivo slider

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, nivo-slider

I'm trying to use Chrome developer tools to inspect elements in a page that contains a Nivo-Slider.

The focus repeatedly keeps on jumping to the slider which is very annoying.

Is there a way to avoid this without changing the production code (maybe calling a function on the page)?

You can reproduce the issue [here](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/), if you're using Chrome. Open the page, right-click any element (not the slider) and select 'Inspect Element' then when the slider switches, the focus moves to the slider. Very annoying if you want to inspect other elements in the page especially if they're far from the slider.

Comment: For me it jumps to the top of the DOM. So annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the stop method of the Nivo Slider plugin from the browser console like this `jQuery('#slider').data('nivoslider').stop()`. Replace '#slider' in the jQuery constructor with the id of the element on your page that the plugin is bound to. For example, on the demo page running `jQuery('#nivoslider-156').data('nivoslider').stop()` from the console should stop the Nivo Slider from animating.